# How to Access a file in a packaged JAR properly

Tags: java, maven

I created a simple Java-Program which creates an “word”-file based on an “.docx” template.
When I compile the program with maven the program always creates a new file, but instead creating a new one it should use the template in the resource folder.

This is my pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <!-- ... -->
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>xyz.nextn.app.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This is my Main- Class

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Main instance = new Main();
    
    File template = instance.convertInputStreamToFile(instance.getFileAsIOStream("template/template.docx"), "template.docx");
    System.out.println(template.getAbsolutePath());

    XWPFTemplate.compile(template.getAbsolutePath()).render(new HashMap<String, Object>(){{
        put("title", "poi-tl template engine");
    }}).writeToFile("out_template.docx");
}


public File convertInputStreamToFile(InputStream is,String name) {
    File file = new File(name);
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        while ((read = is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            fos.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return file;
}

private InputStream getFileAsIOStream(final String fileName)
{
    InputStream ioStream = this.getClass()
            .getClassLoader()
            .getResourceAsStream(fileName);

    if (ioStream == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(fileName + " is not found");
    }
    return ioStream;
}
```

This is my Project structure

[File Structur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ol2s.png)

After running `mvn clean package` and starting the program it always creates a new template.docx in the root directory.  But I want use the template in the packaged JAR

[comile output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejfN5.png)

Comment: By “the program always creates a new file” did you mean that the program always creates a new *empty* file?

Comment: yes, always an empty .docx file